# Creek discovery. Two structures at opposing ends of the bank. What are they?

Tags: rivers

I found these structures in a fairly inaccessible area of the creek. The oven like construction is made of bricks (which can be found around in the creek bed itself due to runoff) and mud for the seal (also probably from the creek). It also has some pieces of asphalt I think. It is located on the right hand side of the creek if you are walking upstream. The hole on the side makes it really look like it is meant for an oven. However, as you can verify, it remains unused.

Facing it, on the other side of the bank, lies another structure. It has a metal pole bent in an upside down U shape. And a series of stones forming a square whose two foremost corners meet the metal pole's two ends.

Any ideas what it is?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Images included from [my picture album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG137.jpg).

Comment: It's just a little house made by kids playing by the creek, probably with the help of a parent. Something fun made out of garbage and piled rocks, nothing more.

Comment: as @ShemSeger it looks like a little fairy house, they pop up in the UK too (along with fairy doors)

Comment: @IsopycnalOscillation Hey! Who gave you permission to take photos of my house!

Comment: Image link is not available.

Comment: What country is was the photo taken in?

Comment: @Citizen Murica

Comment: Looks like some kids playing.  One interesting note is their use of mud to make a simple mortar.  If you mix straw or grass in with mud you can make a very effective mortar to seal up survival shelters.

Comment: Is there a trail or road remnant at either end?  It looks like brick for the fairy house.  Is there a plausible source for brick?  The base looks like a thin slab of concrete.  Is it? It looks like the kind of feature you see in brick built factories in Victorian England.  Remnants of a beam stabilization?  (Keep the beam upright, not lying flat.)  Walk upstream and down stream and see if you find more remnants.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen these or very similar pics before.  Did you ask on another site?

I can't tell from the pix if there is mortar or just mud holding the stones together.

In a similar question it turned out there had been a bridge upstream that was taken out by either flood or ice dam.  The materials were spread for several miles down stream.  Some stonework was still intact in chunks.

The rebar I think is recent:  Someone using a chunk as a convenient way to dry socks around the campfire.  The rectangle of rocks looks much more ephemeral than the stone work in the other pix.